# Visibility of a grid

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to use a grid in WPF to simulate a scoreboard. But it doesn't seem to be visible while running the app.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Here's the top part of the declaration of the grid (XAML):

```
<Grid Height="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="187,12,0,0" Name="grid1"
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="454" Opacity="100" OpacityMask="Black">
```

Comment: There could be a million reasons -- can you narrow it down for us by posting some code?

Comment: `Grid` is a layout control in WPF this is not visible by default because it used to arrange controls. Can you be more specify what do you expect to see? Maybe you can try to set `ShowGridLines="true"`. And what happen is you remove the  `Opacity` and `OpacityMask` properties?

Comment: @nemesv I'm just trying to simulate a scoreboard. I thought making the grid visible made a good and simple way to do it. I did remove the `Opacity`and `OpacityMask` but it becomes invisible. `ShowGridLines="true"` makes the grid visible excluding the border lines, and somehow not pleasant to the eye.

Comment: Yes, as @nemesv indicates, you need to add things to the `Grid`, it is a container (layout control) that holds other visual elements.  If you just want to see that it's there, you could just set `Background="Red"`.

Comment: The `Grid` may be a good choice for laying out controls to look like a scoreboard, but in order to display text and numbers in the scoreboard, you'll need to add `TextBlock`s or other controls to the grid to display the information. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628(v=vs.90).aspx) and  [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans) as some examples of what it means to be a layout container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout elements don't generally have visibility themselves.  You need to put content inside the layout element in order to have visible items.